# Windows 11: Empty shadow copy tab

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, vss

On my Windows 10 computers, I have a scheduled task to create shadow copies at regular time intervals. Works great.
The command is `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe shadowcopy call create Volume=C:\`
I can access the shadow copies from the file explorer ("Previous Versions" tab), command line, or whatever appropriate software.

On my Windows 11 computers, the very same scheduled task also do the job. But the shadow copies are not visible from the explorer:
[image]

The command line `vssadmin list shadows` display them correctly, and softwares like "Shadow Explorer" also display them.
[image]

The command line result is exactly the same on Windows 10 and 11.
If I put the Windows 11's disk into an USB enclosure, and connect it to a Windows 10 computer, the file explorer correctly display the "Previous Versions" tab. So this is 100% related to Windows 11 file explorer.

All my Windows 11 computers exhibit the same behaviour. Fresh install, or upgraded from Windows 10.

Question: how can I have the explorer's tab "Previous Versions" working again? (because it is much more handy than command line or a non default software).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently a bug in Windows 11.
Until it's fixed by Microsoft, you will need to access shadow copies
using other software than Explorer. You could signal it via the
Feedback Hub.

This bug is already discussed in the post
[Windows 11 - Previous versions, cannot seem to get it working](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/windows-11-previous-versions-cannot-seem-to-get-it-working.10262/)
where after a long discussion the participants reached the
above conclusion.